# Multiple IF statements without Nested IFs

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have two columns in a table: `column_A` with `3` different values `a1, a2, a3` and `column_B` with `5` different values `b1, b2, b3, b4, b5`. I have to create `column_C` in Excel based on the following logic -

```
>     if (A=a1)
>         if(B=b1 or B=b2)
>               output=a1_yes
>         else
>               output = a1_no
>     elseif(A=a2)
>         if(B=b3 or B=b4)
>               output = a2_yes
>         else
>               output = a2_no
>     elseif(A=a3)
>         if(B=b5)
>               output = a3_yes
>         else
>               output = a3_no
```

Nested `if-else` makes the logic very complex. Is there any function we could use for simplicity and avoid nested `if-else`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get rid of the nested `if-else`, I would suggest you use the function Switch instead. 
You can concatenate the columns you are validating and provide results based on the possible values.

**Given the table below:** 
Make 1
Model 1
Color 1

Use the formula:

```
SWITCH(expression,value1,result1,default_or_value2,result2,...)
```

**Example**:

```
=SWITCH(CONCAT(A1,B1),"Make1","a1_yes","Make2","a1_yes","a2_yes")
```

### Reference

[SWITCH Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks Andre. Can you please explain why you used Concatenate function in the example?

Comment: @Neel The Concat function will provide you the final result that you would have after checking all conditions in the nested if.  
**Example Nested if:**
`if A1 = 'A' 
  if B1 = 'B' or B1 = 'BB'
   output = 'a1yes'`

**Same example using Concat+Switch:**
`SWITCH(CONCAT(A1,B1), 'AB','a1yes','ABB','a1yes')`

Answer (score 0):

I think in such complex cases it is best to create a lookup table and find the required value with the `LOOKUP` function which works starting from Excel 2007:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A2=$H$2:$H$9)*(B2=$I$2:$I$9)+(A2=$H$2:$H$9)*(""=$I$2:$I$9)),$J$2:$J$9)
```

In the case of GS, this formula must be included in the `ARRAYFORMULA` function.

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/((A2=$H$2:$H$9)*(B2=$I$2:$I$9)+(A2=$H$2:$H$9)*(""=$I$2:$I$9)),$J$2:$J$9))
```

[image]

If you can't create lookup table here will be option without it:

```
=LOOKUP(2,
  1/((A2={"a1","a1","a1","a2","a2","a2","a3","a3"})
  *(B2={"","b1","b2","","b3","b4","","b5"})
  +(A2={"a1","a1","a1","a2","a2","a2","a3","a3"})
  *(""={"","b1","b2","","b3","b4","","b5"})),
  {"a1_no","a1_yes","a1_yes","a2_no","a2_yes","a2_yes","a3_no","a3_yes"})
```